# Using the session hash outside of a route

Tags: ruby, session, scope, sinatra

In my sinatra application, I would like to create some methods for manipulating the session. I would like to declare all of those methods in a module, and have that module outside any routes. For example:

```
enable :sessions

module SessionEditing
    def setup
        session[:value] = "something"
    end
end

get "/" do
    SessionEditing.setup
    redirect "/test"
end

get "/otherRoute" do
    SessionEditing.setup
    redirect "/test"
end

get "/test"
    puts session[:value] #=> "something"
end
```

I thought that there might be a way to elevate the scope of `session`, but I haven't been able to find out how. I also have learned that passing `session` into the method doesn't work because you can't set it back, even if the method returns a new `session` setting `session = SessionEditing.setup(session)` will not actually make the session change. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `SessionEditing.setup(session)` will allow you to modify the session. The problem is `SessionEditing is incorrectly implemented. Try:

```
module SessionEditing
  def self.setup
    session[:value] = "something"
  end
end
```

When you call `SessionEditing.setup`, you are calling the  module method `.setup`, which is why you need to define the method with `self`, as it defines `setup` as a class method.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! And I thought I was totally lost! I've spent a week on this problem!